# Motherboard core clock speed vs RAM core clock speed

Tags: memory, cpu

If I have a CPU using a bus speed of 100MHz (before the multiplier is used)
and a DDR3-1600 RAM module calculated at

200MHz x 2 for DDR x 4 for the I/O buffer on DDR3 = 1600.

Where is the RAM getting its core RAM clock speed from the 200 in this case?